# Unit wise calculation in billing

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a billing system in wpf for a grocery shop.
If I have a unit in a piece (pc) then the amount will be calculated easily, like amount = qty*unitRate.

For eg following products have opening balance:

1. Product having a toothpaste (in pc)
2. Product having oil (In litre)
3. Product having flour (in kg)

How to make the calculation in such a way that all the amount of above products? shall be calculated? at the time of sale.

Do I have to write a formula for unit conversion for each volume or something else?

What type of database structure do I have to prepare for this?

Comment: Whats the problem with assuming pc, litre and kg as your unit? If you define 1$ as the price for a kg of flour, and want to buy 2,5 kg you can simply multiply 1$ by the 2,5 kg.

Comment: I'd argue that this is not related to programming itself, but first and foremost to understanding a problem.

Comment: What logic do you have in mind? Did you try to convert that to code? What issue you are facing with that code?

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far? In fact, where is your problem? Normally you'd store the unit, the price per unit and the amount of units and that's it. Just multiply and be done with it.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply take pc, litre and kg as your base units.

```
static decimal GetPrice (decimal qty, decimal unitRate)
{
    return qty * unitRate;
}
```

Assume that you want to buy 2,5 kg of flour, and the price for 1 kg is 1$, you could simply call the method with

```
GetPrice(2.5m, 1);
```

Just make sure that (in your database) you have the products **cost per unit**, meaning for toothpaste the price for one tube, for oil the price for one litre and for flour the cost for one kg.

Comment: Don't use `float`. Use `decimal` for price and quantities. `float` (and `double`) are for scientific values.

Comment: And what about the rest of the OP's question? They have asked more than just this.